# AS3 for exit button in CS6

Tags: flash, flash-cs6

this is my AS3 coding for Exit button which i built in CS6. But, when i tested the movie in flash, it doesn't work to quit the game. What is the problem, can anyone tell me?Thanks.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent
import flash.system.fscommand;
quit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickHandler);

function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
   fscommand("quit");
}
```

Comment: I don't think the flash IDE will receive fscommands.  If you export as a projector then it should work for you

Comment: i think fscommand works ok in cs6, but specific "quit" command only works in standalone flash player

Comment: Thanks your comments.
1)How to export as a projector?
2)what does standalone flash player mean?

Comment: It works in standalone flash player. Solve one of my problems. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but it bothered me that it didn't have any marked answers.

I believe the correct answer came from LDMediaServices: The Flash IDE test environment does not receive fscommands.

Though I've been able to test to ensure that my fscommands are sent through the Scaleform Launcher plugin provided by UDK. This, however, does not test the response from whatever is to receive these commands.

http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/SettingUpScaleformGFx.html